# Laravel profile edit

Tags: laravel, edit, profile

Alright , I have used this way to save the users info  and It works perfect,

```
 static public function memberSave($request) {

        $signup = false;

        $member = new Members();
        $member->name = $request['name'];
        $member->email = $request['email'];
        $member->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
        $member->save();

        if (!empty($member->id)) {

            $new_id = $member->id;
            DB::insert("INSERT INTO roles VALUES ($new_id, 5613)");
            $signup = true;
            Session::flash('sm', 'Thank you! You have signed up successfully!');
        }

        return $signup;
    }
```

but when making this for editing the profile(by user) It doesn't work
becuase I use new(); (making object)

I also didn't succeed to use find(); so I tried to use this

```
static public function saveProfile($id,$name,$email,$password) {


        $sql = "UPDATE members SET name=?,email=?,password=? WHERE id=?";
        $member = DB::select($sql, [$name,$email,$password,$id]);
```

but when I want to bcrypt the password in laravel doesnt work .

this is the code also in the second page

```
public function postProfile(ProfileValidation $request) {
    if (Members::saveProfile($request['id'], $request['name'], $request['email'], $request['password'])) {

        return redirect('');
    }
}
```

I hope getting helped for editing the users profile by laravel , thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Members` class must extend `Eloquent\Model` for following this code to work.

```
class Members extends Model {
    // optional
    protected $table = 'members';
...
```

To find and update the member using email,

```
// find the single member
$member = Members::where('email', request['email'])->first();
// update the member
$member->name = $request['name'];
$member->password = $request['password'];
// now save the updated member
$member->save();
```

In order to to encrypt Password, Laravel provides `Hash` Facade,

```
// import this
use Hash;
...
// encrypt Password
$encrypted = Hash::make($request['password']);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your user automatically hash the password at your model put:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

and you can directly check for the user if exist create new or update it:

```
public function saveMember($request)
{
    $member = Member::findOrNew($request->email);
    //All your input you want to save
    $member->save();
}
```